# emberjs - Add actions to Ember.Service

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to add actions to an Ember.Service in Ember 1.10 but I've had to alias `_actions` to the `actions` hash to get it working, am I missing something?

```
export default Ember.Service.extend(Ember.ActionHandler, {
  actions:{
    addItem: function(label) {
      console.log(label);
    }
  },

  setup: Ember.on('init', function(){
    this._actions = this.actions;
  })
});
```

Looking at the ember source, the `triggerEvent` method queries the `_actions` hash:

```
if (handler._actions && handler._actions[name]) {
  if (handler._actions[name].apply(handler, args) === true) {
    eventWasHandled = true;
  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```

I think I am missing something.

Comment: Why are you using actions in a service?

Comment: I want pubsub and it seemed logical to use the existing framework.

Comment: Actions up and data down

Comment: I wrote a little addon to help with this https://github.com/knownasilya/ember-action-services

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actions bubble from a template into a view, then controller, then through routes. No action ever reaches a service, unless you manually do `myService.send('someAction')`.

Instead of service actions, use service methods.

Just declare a method on a service, then do, for example, in a controller:

```
  myService: Ember.inject.service(),
  actions: {
    someAction: function(arg) {
      this.get('myService').someMethod(arg);
    }
  }
```

Comment: is it possible to make this go straight to the service without handling it in the component first?

Comment: Also, if you're gonna do it in a component, consider injecting the service into a controller and passing it from controller to component. This will make your component loosely coupled and reusable.

Answer (score 1):

As a simpler solution and to answer dagda1, you can skip the intermediate action by setting the target on the template action. This is useful if you have a service backed component and need to maybe use the same action in various instances and want to avoid having to declare the action in the template and each respective component multiple times.

Inject the service in context:

`myService: inject.service()`

Target the service in your template:

`{{action 'myServiceAction' target=myService}}`

This will then target the actions hash on the service:

```
actions: {
  myServiceAction() {
    ...
  }
}
```